# How to access structure type pointer variable which is declared inside the class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, data-structures, structure

```
class btree{
 public:
 int non,vor;
 string str;
 struct tree{
   int data;
   struct tree *lnode;
   struct tree *rnode;
    };
};
int main(){
}
```

how to access structure type pointer lnode in main is it even possible help????

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking about? Just create an instance, of said `struct`, and do whatever you want with the variable? `btree::tree t; t.lnode = /*whatever*/;`?

Comment: lnode is a pointer type variable , how can i access it with dot operator i.e myTree.node.lnode=10; i cannot do such type of assignment neither can i assign an address of another node using dot(.) operator

Comment: "_i cannot do such type of assignment neither can i assign an address of another node using dot(.) operator_" I am sorry, but what? `lnode` is a pointer, yes. Hence, you couldn't do `lnode.data = 10;`, but what is stopping from doing `btree::tree t; t.lnode = new btree::tree;`? You can't use dot operator on a pointer, but such example doesn't do that. I use dot operator on an instance, not on pointer. Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

You defined the `struct tree`, but didn't actually put any into your `btree`. Do this instead:

```
class btree {
public:
    int non, vor;
    string str;
    struct tree {
        int data;
        struct tree *lnode;
        struct tree *rnode;
    } node; // note the "node" that was added, now btree contains a struct tree named "node"
};
```

Access it like this:

```
int main() {
    btree myTree;
    myTree.node.data = 10;
}
```

Comment: The same way. `myTree.node.lnode` and `myTree.node.rnode`.

Comment: lnode is a pointer type variable , how can i access it with dot operator i.e myTree.node.lnode=10;   i cannot do such type of assignment neither can i assign an address of another node using dot(.) operator

Comment: By making a `struct tree` (in a constructor/method of `btree` because `struct tree` isn't going to be visible outside of that). Then you assign that `struct tree` to `myTree.node.lnode` and then you can do `myTree.node.lnode->data = 10;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, accessing the structure type pointer lnode declared inside the tree structure in your btree class is possible. However, since the tree structure is nested within the btree class and lnode is a private member of that nested structure, accessing it directly from main() isn't straightforward.

To access lnode from main(), you'll need to provide public member functions within the btree class that allow manipulation of the tree structure's members.

Here's an example of how you might do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class btree {
public:
    int non, vor;
    string str;

    struct tree {
        int data;
        tree* lnode;
        tree* rnode;
    };

    tree* getLNode() {
        return &treenode;
    }

private:
    tree treenode;
};

int main() {
    btree treeObj;

    btree::tree* lnodePtr = treeObj.getLNode();

    lnodePtr->data = 42;

    cout << "Updated data in lnode: " << lnodePtr->data << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here, getLNode() is a public member function of the btree class that returns a pointer to the tree structure. This allows you to access and manipulate the members of the tree structure (including lnode) from main() by using an instance of the btree class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.